# Fast Implementation for Tagging Events Prior to Tagged Event

Tags: r

I need a faster / vectorized way of achieving the following b/c doing it with a loop takes ages for a large data set with several million entries. But so far nothing good comes to my mind.

```
df <- data.frame(
    id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4),
     t = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
   tag = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  tag2 = 0 # this is supposed to be computed
)

tag_items <- function(df) {
  is1 <- FALSE
  item <- -1

  for(i in nrow(df):1) {
    curr <- df[i,"tag"]

    if(curr == 0) {
      if(item != df[i,"id"]) {
        is1 <- FALSE
        item <- -1
      } else {
        if(is1) {
          df[i,"tag2"] <- 1
        } else {
          df[i,"tag2"] <- 0
        }
      }
    } else if(curr == 1) {
      is1 <- TRUE
      item <- df[i,"id"]
      df[i,"tag2"] <- 1
    } 
  }

  return(df)
}
```

The tagging applied:

```
> tag_items(df)

   id t tag tag2
1   1 1   0    1
2   1 2   0    1
3   1 3   1    1
4   1 4   0    0
5   2 1   0    1
6   2 2   0    1
7   2 3   1    1
8   2 4   0    0
9   2 5   0    0
10  2 6   0    0
11  3 1   1    1
12  3 2   0    0
13  3 3   0    0
14  4 1   0    0
15  4 2   0    0
16  4 3   0    0
```

---

Verbal explanation:

`df` is sorted chronologically by `id` and by `t`(ime). For a given `id` the value of `tag2` is supposed to be 1 if there is an entry with value of `tag` being 1 afterwards or if `tag` is 1 for that same entry.

---

A possible method would be: split by id -> FOCB -> unsplit - but I suspect that method won't be very fast either due to sequential FOCB.

FOCB = First Observation Carried Backward (LOCF turned around)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df), id)[,tag2:=replace(tag2, seq(which(tag==1)),1) , by=id]
df
#   id t tag tag2
#1:  1 1   0    1
#2:  1 2   0    1
#3:  1 3   1    1
#4:  1 4   0    0
#5:  2 1   0    1
#6:  2 2   0    1
#7:  2 3   1    1
#8:  2 4   0    0
#9:  2 5   0    0
#10: 2 6   0    0
#11: 3 1   1    1
#12: 3 2   0    0
#13: 3 3   0    0
#14: 4 1   0    0
#15: 4 2   0    0
#16: 4 3   0    0
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   mutate(tag2= replace(tag2, seq(which(tag==1)),1))
```

Comment: Nice one and fast thinking. Is there a reason you keying it?

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Thanks, I thought that would be a bit faster.

Comment: it's blazingly fast - very impressive!

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility using `cumsum` on the `rev`ersed target vector, and then `rev`ersing the result:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(tag2 = rev(cumsum(rev(tag))))
#    id t tag tag2
# 1   1 1   0    1
# 2   1 2   0    1
# 3   1 3   1    1
# 4   1 4   0    0
# 5   2 1   0    1
# 6   2 2   0    1
# 7   2 3   1    1
# 8   2 4   0    0
# 9   2 5   0    0
# 10  2 6   0    0
# 11  3 1   1    1
# 12  3 2   0    0
# 13  3 3   0    0
# 14  4 1   0    0
# 15  4 2   0    0
# 16  4 3   0    0
```

Or apply same function in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df), id)[ , tag2 := rev(cumsum(rev(tag))), by = id]
```